# testing instance variable equivalence (RSpec)

Tags: ruby, rspec

Apologies if this has been asked before. I'm trying to make the game mastermind using oop. The aim of the class is to check if two instance variables (a code and a guess) are equal or not. How do I set the instance variables in order to test this? Thanks!

```
class MastermindCodechecker
  def initialize(code, guess)
    @code = code
    @guess = guess
  end

  def check?
    # return true if @code == @guess
  end
end
```

Comment: `@code == @guess` is what you need (and you already have it). What's the question then?

Answer (score 2):

```
RSpec.describe 'MastermindCodechecker' do
  describe '#check?' do
    context 'when code and guess are different' do
      @foo = MastermindCodechecker.new('bar', 'baz')

      it 'returns false after check' do
        expect(@foo.check?).to eq false
      end
    end

    context 'when code and guess are equal' do
      @foo = MastermindCodechecker.new('bar', 'bar')

      it 'returns true after check' do
        expect(@foo.check?).to eq true
      end
    end
  end
end
```